# Error with writing a list to a csv file using python pandas

Tags: python, list, csv

i have a list. which has 8 lists inside it and each list have 50 elements

```
ex - [[list 1 with 50 elements ],[list 2 with 50]........,[list 8 with 50]]
```

i want to write the list to a CSV file as all 8 lists inside the outer list as 8 columns and 50 items in each.But when i try to write it it brings an error message saying i need 50 columns instead of 8. how to fix this problem?

```
df = ps.DataFrame( data = newresult , columns=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'])
df.to_csv("k-mean-test.csv", index = False)
```

Comment: What did you use csv module? or DictWriter?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
lists = [range(10)] * 3
df = pd.DataFrame(lists)
print df.to_csv(index=False, header=False)
```

This gives you:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Comment: mmmm yeah but i am taking data from a long process john. there is no way i could simplified result as that.

Comment: If your data is as you said it is, this solution should work.  Your list of lists is longer and wider than mine, sure, but the rest looks the same.

Comment: i am sorry. I understood it wrong. Yeah it come out this way. But i want transpose of your result. First column 0-9, 2nd column 0-9 and third column 0-9

Comment: @Optimuskck: OK then do `df.T.to_csv(...)`.